trying to get blob image from a url using selenium and java
I'm trying to download an image blob from a web page. Blob url looks like : blob:https://example.com/43bdcaf9-7d30-4b80-9306-7e411533b960
The image can be downloaded and converted to base64 text if I use javascript like below (in Chrome browser and running code as a browser extension):
async function blobToBase64(blobUrl) {
    console.log(blobUrl);
    const response = await fetch(blobUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
    return base64String;
}

I need the same thing to be done in Java using Selenium Chrome driver, but not able to achieve it. I have tried below code:
                    String blob = "";
                    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
                        blob = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("const response = await fetch('" + baseUrl
                                + "');" + "const blob = await response.blob();"
                                + "const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();"
                                + "const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));"
                                + "return base64String;").toString();

                        System.out.println(blob);
                    }

but I get failed to fetch url error.
Please help to fetch the image blob and convert to base64 String
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to fetch
  (Session info: chrome=130.0.6723.91)
Build info: version: '4.18.1', revision: 'b1d3319b48'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '23'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

Thanks in advance.

Don't use JavaScriptExecutor
public static String blobToBase64(InputStream blobInputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = blobInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
    }

This input stream you can get from http url
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.getInputStream();// this is what you will need to invoke above method


HttpURLConnection  does not understand blob URL "blob:https://example.com/06fe281d-348a-4ef8-8f1f-3cc95e276763". and without specifying blol, HttpURLConnection tries to open a connection on internet which does not exist
